# How could I retrieve data from the last week or month using prisma query

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

how can you make a query in Prism to filter data by date?
For example, I would like to take data from the last week or month

```
return await prisma.orders.findMany({
    where: {
      date: {
      },
    },
  });
```

I don't really know what to do after the date..
How could I filter in this light?
For example, data from the last week and the last month

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to filter between a date range, you can get today's date and the date of last week/month and get the records through [lte](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#lte) and [gte](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#gte) operators.

```js
return await prisma.orders.findMany({
    where: {
      date: {
        lte: 2022-10-30,
        gte: 2022-10-15,
      },
    },
  });
```

Here is an [example](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#get-all-post-records-where-date_created-is-greater-than-march-19th-2020) from Prisma Documentation